# JUnit Rule TemporaryFolder arbitrarily throws an IOException

Tags: java, junit, junit4, ioexception

I am facing a weird problem here...

I have a JUnit implementing a few tests. This class looks like the following:

```
public class MyTest {

    @Rule
    public TemporaryFolder folder = new TemporaryFolder();

    @Test
    public void myTest1() throws IOException {
        String destinationPath = folder.newFile("destination1.txt").getPath();
        // Do things
    }

    @Test
    public void myTest2() throws IOException {
        String destinationPath = folder.newFile("destination2.txt").getPath();
        // Do things
    }

    @Test
    public void myTest3() throws IOException {
        String destinationPath = folder.newFile("destination.txt").getPath();
        // Do things
    }
}
```

This test class used to work in my previous environment and still does in Continuum.

Yet, when launching from Eclipse none, some, or all of the tests arbitrarily throw an `IOException` such as:

```
java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:883)
    at org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder.newFile(TemporaryFolder.java:53)
    at MyTest.myTest2(MyTest.java:50)
```

I have the exact same problem running JUnit 4.9 or JUnit 4.10 ...

How can I fix that so that it works properly?

Comment: That should work. Which `Runner` are you using to run the tests? Are they concurrent? You might want to debug more, i.e. sout the `folder` variable too see where it points when the problem occurs.

Comment: Can you say what you're doing in the tests? Are you writing to the files? Also, do you have windows indexation running?

Comment: Yes the aim of the program is to process data and to write a file as output. No windows indexation is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try disabling your anti-virus protection.

I was having same problem, and after disabling Kaspersky everything was working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, this might be more a windows related problem than a JUnit one. Somehow, you could be missing the right to create folders/files while being logged in as a "limited rights user".

I guess you could try creating a temporary folder yourslef, just as JUnit does:

```
        File folder= File.createTempFile("junit", "");
```

If the statement above throws the same error, you should investigate your windows user rights, maybe try running the test under a "full-rights" user.

Answer (score 0):

What seemed to help in my case was explicitly creating the root folder; in your case, throwing a `folder.create()` somewhere into your code.

Ugly, I know.